# MudBlazor Nested Menu Hover on nested child opens and closes that child dialog rapidly and isn't clickable

Tags: hover, blazor-server-side, menuitem, mudblazor

I am writing a nested menu component in Blazor with MudBlazor nested menu components, like described in in the documentation here: https://www.mudblazor.com/components/menu#nested-menu
However, no matter where in my application i try to insert a simple nested menu like this

```
<MudMenu Label="TestMenu">
    <MudMenuItem>1</MudMenuItem>
    <MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenu ActivationEvent="MouseEvent.MouseOver">
            <ActivatorContent>2</ActivatorContent>
            <ChildContent>
                <MudMenuItem>2.1</MudMenuItem>
                <MudMenuItem>2.2</MudMenuItem>
            </ChildContent>
        </MudMenu>
    </MudMenuItem>
</MudMenu>
```

It will flicker open and closed continously when one of the nested menu items is hovered (e.g. item 2.1)

I have moved the menu all over my application, it is happening everywhere
I have tried putting @onmouseover:stoppropagation="true" in several places in the menu, that did not help
I can't replicate this problem in TryMudBlazor

Are there any config things I need to make sure it works? Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using server-side-rendering? If you do maybe have a look at https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8179

Comment: @Uerschel I do, but the menus do get opened, the behaviour of the nested ones just is kind of broken. I am going to try this anyways, thanks.